# Remove div class based on child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html like this

```
<div class="accordion_in1 accordion_in acc_active">
    <div class="acc_head" id="removeArrow">
        <div class="acc_icon_expand"></div>
        <a href="/Investor-Relations">Investor Relations</a>
    </div>
    <div class="acc_content" style="display: block;">
        <div class="acc_content_faq1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Profile" id="ctl00_ctl22_rep1_ctl06_rep2_ctl01_hypLevel2">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="acc_content_faq1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Directors" id="ctl00_ctl22_rep1_ctl06_rep2_ctl02_hypLevel2">Directors</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to remove the class `acc_head` from the second div if there is no div with class `acc_content`

I tried to get this in jquery like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        if ($("accordion_in > div.acc_content").length < 0) {
            $('#removeArrow').removeClass('.acc_head')
        }

                });
 </script>
```

But I can't able to remove the class.Can any one help
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: `$collection.length < 0` is always `false`.

Comment: Remove the dot before the name of the class : `$('#removeArrow').removeClass('acc_head')`

Comment: there minor mistake in jquery code 1) dot is missing in if condition for 'accordion_in' cssclass selection 2) if condition is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If there is no selector with `accordion_in > div.acc_content`, the length is 0, not a value less than 0.

Try this code.

```
    if (!$("accordion_in > div.acc_content").length) {
        $('#removeArrow').removeClass('.acc_head')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
if ($("accordion_in > div.acc_content").length) {
    $('#removeArrow').removeClass('acc_head')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        if (($(".acc_active").find("div.acc_content")).length == 0) {
            $('#removeArrow').removeClass('.acc_head');
        }

                });
 </script>
```